# Autorelease pool. Drain and retain

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am learning ARC right now. Am I right, saying, that objects in autorelease pool remove only after drain and if they are not retained?

Answer (score 0):

Extract from apple documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/)

> In a reference-counted environment (as opposed to one which uses
>   garbage collection), an NSAutoreleasePool object contains objects that
>   have received an autorelease message and when drained it sends a
>   release message to each of those objects. Thus, sending autorelease
>   instead of release to an object extends the lifetime of that object at
>   least until the pool itself is drained **(it may be longer if the object
>   is subsequently retained)**. An object can be put into the same pool
>   several times, in which case it receives a release message for each
>   time it was put into the pool.

Note: In ARC, retain, release, retainCount, or autorelease cannot be explicitly invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with ARC you don't generally deal with autoreleasePools any more. Sometimes in a big loop you might use `@autoreleasepool` to allow objects to be released, but for the most part just keep strong references to objects you want and weak references to objects where you need a reference but want to prevent retain loops. ARC will magically handle almost everything else.

Answer (score 0):

> objects in autorelease pool remove only after drain and if they are not retained?

Yes. `drain` decrements the retain count of the objects in the autorelease pool. If that causes the retain count of an object to fall to zero, it is destroyed as usual (and is then obviously no longer in the pool, as it no longer exists).